# Removing double quote in <img src="">

Tags: image, src

I've faced the issue: i have image path storing in cookie. So when i'm trying to change

```
 <img src="...">
```

with help of jQuery by setting the 'src' attribute of the img like this

```
$('#hero3').attr('src', getCookieValue('Hero3'));
```

i got

```
<img src=""http://mypath"">
```

and the image is not changed. I mean, those **double-double** quotes are making the image path wrong, but actually it's right. How can I delete those double quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use,

```
<img src='....'>
```

and

```
$('#hero3').attr('src', getCookieValue('Hero3').replace(/"/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks likely that your cookie value contains double quotes.  Either save the cookie value first without double quotes or use replace

```
$('#hero3').attr({
    'src' : getCookieValue('Hero3').replace(/"/g, '')
});
```